# Calculate Total Value In Gridview In ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a website which contains a gridview for view details of Product details... It contains columns like name,area,phnoe no,quantity,price,total.... now I want to calculate total value for that I have to multiply the columns quantity and Price and also put that answer to total column in grid... How shall I do this?

Comment: which way are you using to bind your grid ? What is the reference,datatable,dataset,objectdatasource which ?

Comment: Could you please change your heading from Total Value to Computed Column.. I feel Total Value, can be easily misinterpreted as Group or Grand Total Values...  I would have done it myself, But I dont have enough credit to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three(may be more) ways to accomplish this.
**First** is query database and show result on grid

To do this : Query like 
select name,area,phone,quantity,price,**quantity * price as Total** from YOUR_TABLE
Then bind it into your datagrid

**Second** is before binding your source which is here datatable into the grid,loop for this table for your sum.

To do this: You have datatable but not you have column named Total this time.
Now you need to add a new column as Total into the datatable.

```
DataColumn totalColumn = new DataColumn("Total");
totalColumn.Expression = "Quantity * Price";
totalColumn.DataType = //double,integer 
dataTable.Columns.AddAt(totalColumn, 0);
```

All we have done above is generating a computed column

**Third**,use javascript for cells to assemble your specific values to sum,but this time you need to find your datagrid then your cells in which you should prefer using a javascript framework like jquery.I do not know any reference point for this,but First and second options will be much easier to do

Best Regards
Myra

Comment: +1 for pointing out the computed column way,  But the easier way would be the first way, provided you have access to alter the Query or SP.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple yaar,
if the row index is 0 and your column name in price means ,the following is the way to getvalues,
GridViewID.Rows[0].cells["Price"].ToString()

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement/ wish, you can use Javascript to calculate total on client side if you are not fetching data from database.

You can also do it in code behind but it would be better to use JQuery to fetch the data and calculate it on client side.

Comment: can you give me small sample?

Comment: You can follow these links http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/35343-GridView-Textbox-value-Calculation-using.aspx  http://forums.asp.net/t/1354555.aspx

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

> but i have to it in code behind only

Ok then. You need to a template column to your GridView

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Literal ID="litTotal" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Subscribe to the RowDataBound Event.

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{    
 if(e.Row.RowType == RowType.DataRow)  
 {  
    YourObject _item = (YourObject)e.Row.DataItem; // use quickwatch to figure out how to cast into your desired type
    Literal _litTotal = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("litTotal");
  _litTotal.Text = _item.Quantity * _item.Price;
 }
}
```